# Generate PDF and attach to java mail 

Tags: pdf, jakarta-mail

I have a java class which generate PDF file .. I use java Mail to send email .. Now i want to know how to attach the generated pdf to java mail without saving in local .... 
Is there any method to attch pdf on fly ...

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to create and attach file. You just should get your bytes from your file data, and specify particular content-type. http://www.feedforall.com/mime-types.htm

```
public static class CustomFileDataSource extends FileDataSource {

        private byte[] data;

        public CustomFileDataSource(String fileName, byte[] data) {
            super(fileName);
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return "application/pdf";
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {

            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

    }
    MimeBodyPart filePart = new MimeBodyPart();
    filePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new CustomFileDataSource(file.getFileName(),file.getFile())));
    filePart.setFileName(file.getFileName());
    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    mp.addBodyPart(filePart);
    message.setContent(mp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. It will need at least a temporary place to be saved locally before attached. Can you give the reason why you want something like that? Then we'll be able to suggest a solution for what you really need.

Comment: Our requirement is like not to save in server . May i know why the pdf attachment on fly is not possible .. If i know the reason i can proceed with another option ????

Comment: to use java mail to attach something, you have to specify the path to the file. why temporarily saving the file is not an option for you?

Comment: This is our  requirement to be implemented without any deviation . We have already implemented as you said, however again we are asked not to save temporarily . So in this case proper justification shall be provided to convince them .. Kindly do let me know the exact technical issue to justify without saving temporarily which is not possible...

Comment: As they are 2 separate sequential processes, it is obvious that you can't do that. may be you can save it somewhere else if you are not allowed to save it on a specific server.